# Generics and wildcards with collections in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard, assertj

In a test class using AssertJ, I have code similar to the following:

```
public void someTest() {
    assertThat(getNames()).has(sameNamesAs(getExpectedNames()));
    assertThat(getNames()).doesNotHave(sameNamesAs(getOtherNames()));
}

private List<String> getNames() {
    return null;
}
private List<String> getExpectedNames() {
    return null;
}
private List<String> getOtherNames() {
    return null;
}

private Condition<List<String>> sameNamesAs(List<String> rhs) {
    return new Condition<List<String>>("same names as " + rhs) {
        @Override
        public boolean matches(final List<String> lhs) {
            return lhs.containsAll(rhs) && rhs.containsAll(lhs);
        }
    };
}
```

I get a compilation error on the calls to `has` and `doesNotHave`:

```
has/doesNotHave
(org.assertj.core.api.Condition<? super java.util.List<? extends java.lang.String>>)
in AbstractListAssert cannot be applied
to
(org.assertj.core.api.Condition<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>).
```

I'm new to Java and I don't understand the problem: `java.util.List` is a super-type of `java.util.List` and `java.lang.String` extends `java.lang.String`, don't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the `has` and `doesNotHave` methods take a `Condition<? super List<? extends T>` condition, not a `Condition<? super List<T>>` as you are returning from your `Condition<List<T>> sameNamesAs` method.

You need an instance of the `Condition<List<? extends String>>` type (it's a subclass of the original type `Condition<? super List<? extends String>>`):

```
private Condition<List<? extends String>> sameNamesAs(List<String> rhs) {
    return new Condition<List<? extends String>>("same names as " + rhs) { ... };
}
```

I tried to illustrate this with the following snippet:

```
List<String> list = getNames();

// ELEMENT = String, ACTUAL = List<? extends ELEMENT>
ListAssert<String> assertThat = assertThat(list);

// by the signature, we have to pass Condition<? super ELEMENT> or Condition<? super ACTUAL>
// Condition<? super ACTUAL> = Condition<? super List<? extends String>>
Condition<List<? extends String>> condition = sameNamesAs(list);

// Condition<List<? extends String>> extends Condition<? super List<? extends String>>
assertThat.has(condition);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation. If I understand correctly, my mistake was to believe that `List<String>` is a super-type of `List<? extends String>` while the two types actually have no inheritance relationship. I just don't understand this line in your answer: `// by the signature, we have to pass Condition<? super ELEMENT> or Condition<? super ACTUAL>`. What is `ACTUAL` here?

Comment: @ChristopheFuzier, yes, because `List<String>` is *a child* of `List<? extends String>`. `ACTUAL`, `ELEMENT` are just different generic parameters of methods and the `Assertions` class respectively (`ACTUAL = List<? extends ELEMENT>`)

Comment: I haven't been able to differentiate between the keywords "super" when used in place of "extends". What is difference between Condition<? super ELEMENT> and Condition<? extends ELEMENT>? Why aren't using the lattter?